# Conditions that imply a subgroup normalizes a maximal torus

Tags: algebraic-groups

I remember recently seeing, but I have no memory of where, a result of the following form:

> Let $k$ be a field, $G$ a connected reductive $k$-group, and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ such that ….  Then $H$ normalizes a maximal torus in $G$.

The hypothesis on $H$ is suppressed, and here's why.  At the time, I thought "I'm sure that result will come in handy, so I'd better remember it."  Now, of course, I need such a result, and so I no longer remember it.  Presumably there are many possible things that can fill in the blank, including the annoyingly tautological ("such that $H$ normalizes a maximal torus in $G$").  What are the most interesting ways to fill it in that you know?

There's no harm in assuming $k$ is algebraically closed, but I would prefer not to assume that it has characteristic $0$.  I'm most interested in the case where $H$ is finite, and even étale, but you need not assume that.

Answer (score 1):

Browsing Lie-group questions turned up a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361149/does-a-compact-lie-group-have-finitely-many-conjugacy-classes-of-maximal-abelian#comment910242_361151) from @abx on MO that may have been what I remembered.  I have [asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361149/does-a-compact-lie-group-have-finitely-many-conjugacy-classes-of-maximal-abelian#comment1117439_361151) them to post their comments as an answer, but, in the meantime, I record this as a reminder, in case I forget again.

> Another approach: any abelian (or even nilpotent) subgroup of $G$ is contained in the normalizer of a maximal torus.

Here $G$ is a compact Lie group, but perhaps there is an analogous result for a reductive group over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.  (I originally said "maybe the same is true", but a colleague pointed out to me that it can't be literally the same result; the centre of the unipotent radical of a Borel subgroup of a non-toral reductive group is Abelian, but will not normalise a maximal torus.)  @abx also gave a [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361149/does-a-compact-lie-group-have-finitely-many-conjugacy-classes-of-maximal-abelian#comment910247_361151):

> Bourbaki's Lie IX, §5, Cor. 4 of Théorème 1.

For my reference, this is in no. 4 of §5, on the page labelled LIE IX.49 in my copy.